# How do I simplify this transitive application in Scala

Tags: scala

For a given function call f, with arguments a, b, and c, that calls function g using functions h and i to build the arguments, I can say:

```
f(a)(b)(c) = g( h(a)(b)(c), i(a)(b)(c) )
```

I know that I can create a function such that:

```
g'(h,i)(a)(b)(c) = g(h(a)(b)(c), i(a)(b)(c))
```

so that f can be

```
f = g'(h,i)
```

and thusly applying f(a)(b)(c) will yield the desired result.

I can brute force this from (where f becomes build):

```
def build(a: String)(b: String)(c: String) =
  Message(convA(a)(b)(c), convB(a)(b)(c))
```

to (given that h and i aren't important to be arguments, maybe this is where the disconnect is):

```
def gDash = {
  a:String => b: String => c: String => Message(convA(a)(b)(c), convB(a)(b)(c))
}

def build = a:String => b:String => c:String => gDash(a,b,c)
```

but I still have to specify the entire typing for (a,b,c).  But I've gone from something that should be more complex and fragile to something simpler, but the implementation is actually a bigger mess!  Is there a way to simplify this that doesn't require all this?

If I tupleize the arguments so that:

```
def gDash = implicit composite:(String,String,String) => Message(convA, convB)

def convA(composite: s) => ...
def convB(composite: s) => ...

def f(a: String)(b: String)(c: String) = gDash((a,b,c))
```

I'm not sure that's actually better, I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Methods require you to be explicit with parameters.  Tuples can have type aliases assigned to them, which can help with the excess typing:

```
type S3 = (String, String, String)
```

And you can go back and forth between functions `(A, B) => C` and `A => B => C` with `curried` and `Function.uncurried`.

These give you the tools that you need to make more compact representations of your functions.  For example, if you want something called `build` that has form `String => String => String => Whatever`, you could

```
val build = ((abc: S3) => Message(convA(abc), convB(abc)).curried
```

and then if you want to write `gDash` in place of `Message` you could do something like

```
def dash[A,B,C,D,E](g: (A,B) => C)(h: E=>A, i: E=>B): E => C = 
  (e: E) => g(h(e),i(e))
```

and then uncurry on the way in if you want `E` to actually be three separate string parameters.